# Auto click button via bluetooth?

Tags: c#, multithreading, bluetooth

I use the following code to auto-click a button on my desktop application when I receive the command from tablet via bluetooth:

```
//Auto click record button
if (action_type_received_final == 0)
{
    ButtonAutomationPeer peer2 = new ButtonAutomationPeer(Btn_Record);
    IInvokeProvider invokeProv2 = peer2.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;
    //invokeProv2.Invoke();
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => invokeProv2.Invoke()));

    action_type_received_final = 0;
}
```

I used to get the following exception before I added dispatcher line:

"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"

Now I do not get this exception anymore and code runs, but the button on desktop does not get actually clicked.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Wherever that exchangedata is called right now. If not put this in a seperate method and call it using BeginInvoke.